# Scala: Parsing transformation question

Tags: parsing, scala

I am using Scala's combinator parser as follows:

```
def a = b ~ c ^^ { case x ~ y => A(x,y) }
def b = ... { B() }
def c = ... { C() }
```

now I have a feature change that change within the parsing of the reference of previously parsed `B` to be a `val` in `C`. So `C`'s constructor is something like:

```
C(ref:B)
```

I can imagine, the only way to achieve this is a dirty patch work by assigning the instance of parsed `B` object to `def c` in between the parsing of `a`. Something like following:

```
var temp:B = null

def a = ( b ^^ { case x => temp = x } )
        ~ c(temp) ^^ {case x ~ y => A(x,y} )
```

Is there a standard, clean way of doing this? The definition of `a` can't be broken, it is used in many places in rest of the code.

The other solution is to use `var` instead of `val` and have following:

```
 def a = (b ~ c ) ^^ { case x ~ y => y.ref = c ; A(x,y) }
```

But this is also not acceptable as it would "work" now, but it would involve extra effort and boiler-plate code in future development.

I've not tested this code, as this is a small part and all the changes require a lot of effort so want the expert opinion first.

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the definition of `a`, there is no way to do this cleanly.  The `~` combinator produces a new `Parser` which applies `b` and `c` in sequence, then tuples (well, logically tuples) up the results and returns them as *its* result.  The key point is that the application of `c` is not a function of the output of `b`, thus there is nothing you can do to get the results of `b` inside the application of `c`.

What I would do is add a new combinator which does what you want.  I'm not feeling particularly creative name-wise, but I think this should give you a rough idea:

```
implicit def cleverParserSyntax[A](left: Parser[A]) = new {
  def ~%[B](right: A => Parser[B]): Parser[A ~ B] = for {
    lr <- left
    rr <- right(lr)
  } yield new ~(lr, rr)
}

def a = b ~% c ^^ { case x ~ y => A(x,y) }
def b = ... { B() }
def c(res: B) = ... { C(res) }
```

Comment: Except the `into` method, of course. :-) Which happens to have a very similar type signature... :-)

Comment: Well, I *could* go that route, but it's so much more fun to just come up with something on my own!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly but if C depends on B why not express this in functional way?

```
case class B(...)
case class C(b: B, ...)
case class A(b: B, c: C)

def b: Parser[B] = ... ^^ { B(...) }
def c: Parser[B => C] = ... ^^ { C(_, ...) }
def a: Parser[A] = b ~ c ^^ {  A(b, c(b)) }
```

This way your problem is solved and you have your dependencies expressed explicitly and in concise way.

Comment: I haven't thought of that. I just tested it, and it works indeed perfectly. Very cool! :-)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I realized that this is a really nice example of thinking in functional way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

```
case class B(x: String)
case class C(b: B, x: String)       
case class A(b: B, c: C)

class MyParser extends RegexParsers {               
  def a = b >> c ^^ { case x ~ y => A(x, y) }       
  def b = "\\w+".r ^^ B                             
  def c(b: B) = "\\d+".r ^^ (x => new ~(b, C(b, x)))
}
```

Now, if `B` happens much before `C`, things get more complicated. I suggest, if things get that hairy, to search for the paper about Scala parser, which goes into a lot of very advanced features.